# How to align text after colon

Tags: text, alignment

I would like to align a few lines of text after the colon in each line, so it currently looks like:

Your Membership Number is: 123456789
Your temporary PIN for website access is: 1234

I would like it to look like:

Your Membership Number is:                         123456789
Your temporary PIN for website access is:     1234

Is it possible to do this without using a table?

Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with HTML like this:

```
<div>
    <span class="col1">Your Membership Number is:</span>
    <span>123456789</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="col1">Your temporary PIN for website access is:</span>
    <span>1234</span>
</div>
```

and css like this:

```
.col1 {
width: 300px;
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.content p{
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 280px;
}
.content p span{
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <p>Your Membership Number is:</p><span>123456789</span><br>
    <p>Your temporary PIN for website access is:</p><span>1234</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).